# Как сделать подобие титров на сайте? (информация, которая будет идти снизу вверх)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как реализовать на сайте такую страницу на которой будет идти информация снизу вверх, точно также как титры в конце фильма? Есть одно условия - не использовать Flash, только HTML, CSS, JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вариант:

```js
var div = $('#myDiv');
var height = div.height();
$('html,body').scrollTop(height);
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: 0
}, {
  duration: height / 50 * 1000,
  specialEasing: 'linear'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv' style='width: 100px;'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam hendrerit sollicitudin tellus, ac eleifend velit dictum eu. Duis sit amet eleifend mi. Phasellus aliquam massa ipsum. Integer quis finibus tellus, id lacinia sapien. Quisque ligula elit, tincidunt nec pellentesque vel, bibendum eget turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi non ex rhoncus, pulvinar elit ut, posuere elit. Aliquam a sapien egestas, bibendum risus et, dictum orci. Nunc ac hendrerit elit. Aenean fermentum lacinia neque ac sagittis. Fusce pharetra viverra metus, vel sodales purus pharetra vitae.

Morbi id condimentum mi, ac scelerisque orci. Fusce ut commodo urna, sit amet imperdiet felis. In vel tortor tellus. Suspendisse bibendum odio et ultrices ullamcorper. Cras eget maximus enim. Etiam id volutpat velit, eu tincidunt turpis. In sed vestibulum ipsum. Donec consequat semper libero at tempor.
</div>
```

Comment: @sanic888 То что нужно, только я бы сделал, чтобы текст ехал снизу вверх...

Comment: спешил))))))

Answer (score 6):

Вот еще вариант:

```js
var pos = 0;
height = $(document).height();

var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if(pos <= height)    
        $('#myDiv').css('bottom', pos += 3);
    else 
        clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 50)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #333333;
}
#myDiv {
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;    
    height: 0px;    
    color: #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam hendrerit sollicitudin tellus, ac eleifend velit dictum eu. Duis sit amet eleifend mi. Phasellus aliquam massa ipsum. Integer quis finibus tellus, id lacinia sapien. Quisque ligula elit, tincidunt nec pellentesque vel, bibendum eget turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi non ex rhoncus, pulvinar elit ut, posuere elit. Aliquam a sapien egestas, bibendum risus et, dictum orci. Nunc ac hendrerit elit. Aenean fermentum lacinia neque ac sagittis. Fusce pharetra viverra metus, vel sodales purus pharetra vitae.

Morbi id condimentum mi, ac scelerisque orci. Fusce ut commodo urna, sit amet imperdiet felis. In vel tortor tellus. Suspendisse bibendum odio et ultrices ullamcorper. Cras eget maximus enim. Etiam id volutpat velit, eu tincidunt turpis. In sed vestibulum ipsum. Donec consequat semper libero at tempor.
</div>
```

Comment: @DreamChild Cпасибо, почти то, что нужно. Но как сделать, чтобы текст заезжал за вернюю область видимости экрана, а не останавливался, как в примере на jsfiddle?

Comment: @eprivalov1 ну поиграйтесь с переменными в JS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugt3d/ чуток изменил

Comment: pos += 1  и красота получается =)

а вот так http://jsfiddle.net/wLrQP/9/ то вообще полноценные титры получаются

Comment: @mountpoint ну тогда уж лучше ++pos, нежели pos += 1)

Comment: @DreamChild, где-то в книге Стояна Стефанова JavaScript. Шаблоны читал, что лучше использовать оператор += вместо ++. Но не помню почему)))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/wLrQP/11/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E9C7z/